# Is Gridview Control a complete solution for Web based SQL Server Database Table Editor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, web-controls

After a few failed attemps of integrating the existing Web based sql table editors to my solution, I have decided to write my own Web Based Sql Server table editor and I am thinking of using Gridview control for all the online processes on my database, here my questions:

> 1- Does Gridview a complete solution for SQL Server Database Table
>   Editor ?
>
> 2- Does Gridview the best way to do this?

P.S: What I am tring to do is creating an online admin panel of my application for an end user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datagridview is capable of operations in tables in a web interface, however auto creating a datagridview table when there is a new table added to the database is the hard part. For that reasion creating such an admin menu needs hard working, however if there won't be so much table in the application, you can create your admin panel manually with datagridviews instead of writing an own sql table editor tool.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of grid views and additional objects (for image viewing for example) should be enough for basic data editing.

GridView will allow you to view and edit most fields (except binary and images) from SQL table so in this respect it would work. With lookup tables you would need to use another grid view, maybe in read-only mode. It depends what you expect to have in your table editor.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [sqldatasource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.aspx) control bound to a gridview for each table you need to manage. Sqldatasource will create CRUD operations with a wizard and Gridview will generate columns and commands automatically.

As above, you will work a bit to manage images properly, but all other fieldtype can be managed on the fly.